# How to correctly print a message if a match is found in a linked list?

Tags: c, data-structures, while-loop, linked-list

I'm creating a method that finds the element I want in a linked list and return its index: it should either return index or unsuccessful message, However, my program prints both:

The code:

```
void findVal(int val, myNode *head) {
  myNode *p = NULL;
  p = head;
  int i = 0;
  while (p != NULL){
      if (val == p->val){
        printf("\nthe id is：%d.",i);
        }
      p = p->next;
      i++;
    }
  printf("cannot find the value");
}
```

The result (I want to find all the '4' in a linked list, "123**4**56**4**78"):

```
the id is 3
the id is 6
cannot find the value
```

I then used `return`; this printed the first 4's id then stopped looping. The thing is I have two '4' in my linked list: 123**4**56**4**78.

```
if (val == p->val){
    printf("\nthe id is：%d.",i);
    return;
}
```

Then I thought about using an array to store the index every time a match is found. And after the loop, if the array is empty, then print unsuccessful message, however if the array is not empty, then prints all the indexes.

However, I believe there is a much better solution, so could anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a 'flag' variable, set to zero initially and then set it to non-zero if/when you find a match. If, after the loop has finished, that flag is still zero, then show the "not found" message:

```c
void findVal(int val, myNode *head) {
    int found = 0;
    myNode *p = head;
    int i = 0;
    while (p != NULL){
        if (val == p->val){
            printf("\nthe id is：%d.\n",i);
            found = 1; // Set the flag to non-zero.
        }
        p = p->next;
        i++;
    }
    if (found == 0) {
        printf("cannot find the value\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also replace the `found = 1` with `++found` and that will allow you to display how many matches were found (in an `else` block at the end).